# C++ function prototype outside class

Tags: c++, function, class, oop

In c++ how is this a proper function prototype?

```
class Car{
   //some member variables and functions 
};

Car someFunctionName();
```

I understand that when making member functions and variables you would prototype the function in the class and then later the definition would be something like this

```
double Car::someOtherFunctionName() {}
```

My professor keeps putting the first example of a prototype in example code and I can't seem to grasp the concept. TIA

Comment: C++ simply doesn't require functions to live inside classes.

Comment: Not every function must be part of a class.

Comment: Can you expand your question?

Comment: This really depends on the use-cases and the requirements (and the design or course).

Comment: People like to say that C++ is Object Oriented.  It's not.  It's Object Capable.  You CAN use objects, if you want.

Comment: I have edited your question to distinguish the two names, and to fix the capitalization of `Car`.  If you don't like these changes, feel free to revert my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Not all functions in C++ are member functions.  The function your professor has prototyped is a standalone function which returns a `Car`.

To quote [UKMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6387170/ukmonkey):

> People like to say that C++ is Object Oriented. It's not. It's Object Capable. You CAN use objects, if you want.